# PHP Error - Login/Register Script

Tags: php, authentication, salt

The user registration page works, meaning a the salt and hashed password are saved correctly in the database. The login reports an invalid username/password. I have the salt and password set to varchar(64) in the database if that matters.

I just cant seem to find out why it doesn't work. I would like to believe the error is in the $query or $count variable.

Register:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
#Setup Credentials
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$escapedPW = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
#Salt Credentials
$salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
$saltedPW =  $escapedPW . $salt;
$hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);
#checks and queries
$usercheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$uname'");
$emailcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($usercheck);
$count2 = mysql_num_rows($emailcheck);
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, salt) VALUES ('$uname', '$hashedPW', '$email', '$salt')";
$error = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(empty($_POST['uname']) || empty($_POST['pass']) || empty($_POST['email'] )){
      echo 'A field is empty!';}      
    else{
            if($count != 0){$error = 'Username is already registered.';}
            elseif ($count2 != 0 ) {$error = 'Email is already registered.';}
                else{ mysql_query($query);}
    }
}
?>
```

Login:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
   if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['password'] ) {
    die('You did not complete all of the required fields');
  }
else{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $escapedPW = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $saltquery = "SELECT salt FROM users WHERE username = '$username';";
    $result = mysql_query($saltquery);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $salt = $row['salt'];

    $saltedPW =  $escapedPW . $salt;

    $hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$hashedPW';";
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($count == 0){
      header("location:index.php?status=1");
    }
      else {
              // store cookie $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to index
      session_start(); 
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['password'] = $hashedPW;
      setcookie('username', $username, time()+60 * 60 * 4, '/', 'www.site90.net');
      setcookie('password', $hashedPW, time()+60 * 60 * 4, '/', 'www.site90.net');
      header("location:index.php");
    }
}}
?>
```

Comment: echo $query, are the values the same as the ones in the db ?

Comment: don't use varchar() for binary data like your crypted password. varchar is subject to character translation rules. crypted data MUST come out the same as it went in, and for this you'd need a blob or varbinary type.

Comment: @Dagon - Yes, the query returns the correct information. commenting out the redirect gave me this `Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a5382697/public_html/login.php on line 22`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic are these:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$hashedPW';";
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

They should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$hashedPW';";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

mysql_num_rows() expects that the argument is resource not string:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php